# Hidden Features of MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools

What are the hidden or obscure features of MooTools that every MooTools developer should be aware of?

One feature per answer, please.

Comment: this should be a community wiki

Comment: I agree. I don't see how to do that.

Comment: unfortunately, you need 10k+ rep to do this, I think.

Comment: Found this "old" question +1! Btw... you are 10k+ now :)

Comment: indeed. I protected it for now :) Also, published the Storage uid thing on my blog as it has been in my drafts for a while. updated answer to reflect 1.4.2 changes to API which broke a lot of my code :D http://fragged.org/hacking-mootools-elements-and-storage-uids_1649.html

Answer (score 9):

**Class Mutators**

MooTools has a wonderful feature that allows you to create your own Class mutators. Eg, to add a logger for particular class methods being referenced, you can do:

```
// define the mutator as 'Monitor', use as Mointor: ['methodname', 'method2'...]
Class.Mutators.Monitor = function(methods){
    if (!this.prototype.initialize) this.implement('initialize', function(){});
    return Array.from(methods).concat(this.prototype.Monitor || []);
};

Class.Mutators.initialize = function(initialize){
    return function(){
        Array.from(this.Monitor).each(function(name){
           var original = this[name];
           if (original) this[name] = function() {
               console.log("[LOG] " + name, "[SCOPE]:", this, "[ARGS]", arguments);
               original.apply(this, arguments);
           }
        }, this);
        return initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

and then in the Class:

```
var foo = new Class({

    Monitor: 'bar',

    initialize: function() {
        this.bar("mootools");
    },

    bar: function(what) {
        alert(what);
    }

});

var f = new foo();
f.bar.call({hi:"there from a custom scope"}, "scope 2");
```

Try the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BMsZ7/2/

This little gem has been instrumental to me catching nested bugfoot race condition issues inside a HUUUGE async webapp that would have been so difficult to trace otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

`Function.prototype.protect` is maybe a lesser known nice one.

Is used to have protected methods in classes:

```
var Foo = new Class({

    fooify: function(){
        console.log('can\'t touch me');
    }.protect(),

    barify: function(){
        this.fooify();
    }

});

 var foo = new Foo();
 foo.fooify(); // throws error
 foo.barify(); // logs "can't touch me"
```

Personally I don't use it very often, but it might be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

`Function.prototype.overloadGetter` and `Function.prototype.overloadSetter`

See this post: [What does MooTools' Function.prototype.overloadSetter() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006516/what-does-mootools-function-prototype-overloadsetter-do/4013500#4013500)

Answer (score 4):

There are many features that one can use if you read the source code, although the official line is: `if it's not in the documentation, it is not in the api and it's not supported so do not base your code around it as it may change`

That being said, there are a few things that really can be quite useful. One of my favourites undocumented features is this:

**Referenced Elements have a uid**

Any element that has either being created or is passed on through a selector, gets assigned a property `uid`, which is incremental and unique. Since MooTools 1.4.2, this is only readable via `Slick.uidOf(node)` and not via the old element attr `.uid`. You can now use the new `uniqueNumber` property of any MooTools Element object.

How is that being used? For starters, Element Storage. It relies on the uid as the key in the `Storage` object inside a closure, which will have anything you have `.store`'d for that element.

```
element.store('foo', 'bar');
```

translates to:

```
Storage[Slick.uidOf(element)].foo = 'bar';
```

and

```
element.retrieve('foo'); // getter of the storage key
element.eliminate('foo'); // delete Storage[Slick.uidOf(element)].foo
```

Initializing storage for an element you have created externally, eg, via `var foo = document.createElement('div')` and not Element constructor

```
Slick.uidOf(foo); // makes it compatible with Storage

// same as:
document.id(foo);
```

Things that are stored by the framework into Storage also include all `events` callbacks, `validators` instances, `Fx` instances (tween, morph etc) and so forth.

What can you do knowing the UIDs of elements? Well, cloning an element does NOT get the element's storage or events. You can actually write a new `Element.cloneWithStorage` prototype that will also copy all of the stored values you may have, which is useful upto a point - instances that reference a particular element (such as, `Fx.Tween`) will continue referencing the old element, so it may have unexpected results. This can be useful in moving your own storage, though, all you need is a similar method that will record what you have stored and allow you to clone it.

Example Storage puncture of another Element's data:

```
var foo = new Element('div'),
    uid = foo.uniqueNumber;

foo.store('foo', 'foo only');

var bar = new Element('div');

console.log(bar.retrieve('foo')); // null

bar.uniqueNumber = uid; // force overwrite of uid to the other el

console.log(bar.retrieve('foo')); // foo only - OH NOES

console.log(Object.keys(foo)); // ["uniqueNumber"] - oh dear. enumerable!
```

Answer (score 3):

One of my favorite features that I learned later but wished I knew from the beginning - event pseudos, especially `:once`.

See http://mootools.net/docs/more/Class/Events.Pseudos#Pseudos:once

Comment: you're free to answer any question, doesn't matter how old it is, especially these with no accepted answer. every question has its visitors and may help to someone.

Comment: Yes indeed @jdwire, no limits. StackOverflow gets better when you and I make it better.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks guys. Just joined, so trying to learn my way around.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend reading the excellent [Up the Moo Herd](http://keetology.com/blog/archive/) series by [Mark Obcena](https://twitter.com/#!/keeto), author of [Pro Javascript With MooTools](http://www.apress.com/9781430230540)  :)

Comment: I know this does not fit the wanted format (one feature per answer), but then again, this question does not really fit the SO format  ;)